# Run a PHP function every X minutes

Tags: php

I'm currently writting a forum software to learn PHP. I made some sitewide stats section that I cache in my RAM so the SQL won't get called on every pageload.

I plan to update these stats every ten or so minutes.

Is there a way to implement this without cron? It's fine if I need it but without would be better.

Is there some way with the time so that after every X minutes a visitor would be fine to trigger the re-caching?

Comment: There is no other way than using cron (or similar). Because PHP is only executed during a request to the HTTP server (if we're not in CLI environment). And if it's done PHP "sleeps" till the next request.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Php scripts can run indefinitelly. You should not want to do this but you can.

```
set_time_limit(0); // make it run forever
while(true) {
    doSomethingSpecial();
    sleep(300);
}
```

**Use cron instead.**

Comment: "Use cron instead." <---- this.

Comment: That's only the half truth. PHP scripts have a time limit for it's execution and if it's reached, the PHP skript well be terminated. As it's written in the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time

Comment: There are still some notes for the `set_time_limit()` function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php#refsect1-function.set-time-limit-notes
And on some hosting service providers, PHP scripts are "killed" from the outside.

Comment: Yeah gonna use cron. while(true) is not a great solution for that problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you need exact timing and the function, you want to execute, takes some time, you can do it like this.

```
while(true){
$time_pre = microtime(true);

// your code

$time_post = microtime(true);
$exec_time = $time_post - $time_pre;
sleep($time - $exec_time);
}
```